# can't get netbeans doxygen plugin to work

Tags: c, netbeans, doxygen

so, I'm using NetBeans with doxygen plugin but I just cannot success creating Doxygen doc, that's what I do:

On terminal

```
 doxygen -g
 doxygen Doxyfile
```

...on my nb project folder (where *.c *.h etc are located)

On nb -> tools -> options -> Doxygen Integration I do:

```
doxygen binary -> on my home folder
doxygen.config file -> I tell him to create it on nb project folder
```

But, when I do create doxygen it gives me the error:

*can find resources for bundle org.openide.util.NbBundle$PBundle, key DoxygenProperties.readConfigFile_part1*

I can't find any realted help on the internet, what u guys think is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty much simple I guess after installing the doxygen plugin for netbeans you can go to Tools->Option and follow this image!

[image: Screen]

In the first text box you should specify the binary of the doxygen usually its in /usr/bin/doxygen , if its not there then install it using sudo apt-get install doxygen,

In second box u can either create the config file on some specific directory using the button given or u can do it manually.

And finally in the last box u can give the output directory for the files which will be generated by the doxygen.